# Set library path for JDK in Solaris

Tags: java, path, solaris, x86-64, java-6

I have jdk1.6 running on Solaris 10 on chip AMD64. 
 
I have already set LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.6.0/jre/lib/amd64. 
But it seems java always try to look for library libjvm.so in i386 folder (/usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.6.0/jre/lib/i386/server) instead of amd64 folder (/usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.6.0/jre/lib/amd64/server). 
Do I miss something here? Is there anyway to set environment path for java so that it looks for library in specific path?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works or not. Can you try this?

```
JAVA_LDFLAGS="-L/usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.6.0/jre/lib/amd64/server"
```

Comment: Hi Nevin, it's still the same.